# Why with XeLaTeX in TeXLive, is TeX Gyre Pagella Math font not found

Tags: fonts, tex-gyre-math

I'm using TeXLive 2016 (under OS X). If I run XeLaTeX on the following file (which just modifies the distributed TeX Gyre file `test-xelatex-texgyre_pagella_math.tex`, I get error

```
... fontspec error: "Font-not-found"
the font "TeX Gyre Pagella Math" cannot be found.
```

The source file:

```
%% This is a test file for LaTeX/Unicode-Math for both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,vargreek-shape=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \xi^{2}} d \xi % added by me
\]
%\input math-test.tex % was in original

\end{document}
```

The system `updmap.cfg` file does include entry `qpl.map`.

What else need I do to enable the TeX Gyre Pagella Math font? Is there some additional map file I need to add?

**What works so far:**

Omitting the options, etc., in the preamble now does allow the Pagella Math font to work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \pi \xi^{2}} d \xi% added by me
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: updmap is not relevant here. You probably will have to add your texmf tree to your fontconfig configuration http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4 or load the font by file name.

Comment: You could also make TL fonts visible systemwide with `sudo cp $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf` and `sudo fc-cache -fsv`.

Comment: Can you see the fonts in Font Book?  If not try opening the source .otf files with Font Book and pressing the "install" button.

Comment: In Font Book I see TeX Gyre Pagella Regular, Italic, Bold, and Bold Italic -- each with 2 copies: ` /Users/murray/Library/Fonts/texgyrepagella-regular.otf (active copy)` and `/Library/Fonts/TeX Gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf (inactive copy)`. But I do *not* see any font identified as "TeX Gyre Pagella *Math*". The text TeX Gyre Pagella fonts are working under XeLaTeX; it's only the corresponding math fonts that are not.

Comment: I double-clicked `texgyrepagella-math.otf` in the texlive 2016 tree, opening it in Font Book. But when I pressed the Install button, I got error from Font Validation: "1 serious error was found. Do not use this font." ???

Comment: perhaps try with a new copy: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/download/index_html

Comment: Can you try `\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,vargreek-shape=TeX]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}`?

Comment: Trying `\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,vargreek-shape=TeX]{texgyrepagella-m‌​ath.otf}` gives odd font-not found message: `The font "texgyrepagella-m‌​??th.otf" cannot be found`. Note the `??` instead of `a`!

Comment: @murray Type the command, don't copy-paste. Sometimes stray characters get added in comments and this seems to be one of the cases.

Comment: @egreg: retying fixed it, thanks. I'm still confused as to how one uses the "internal font names" for TeX Gyre. Should that not be "TeX Gyre Pagella". Especially perplexing since the original source file came with the TG collection in TeXLive.

Comment: @murray You can use the “internal name” TeX Gyre Pagella only if the font is known to the system; calling it by file name guarantees the font file in the TeX distribution is used. Personally, I copy the font files from TeX Live into the `/Library/Fonts` folder.

Comment: After installed the font, using Font Book, into `~/Library/Fonts`, the name `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` *does* now work.

Comment: My texlive font config was located at `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf` found with `sudo find / -type f -name texlive-fontconfig.conf` in relation to copying to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf`