# How do I add TeX Gyre Pagella to the Font Book, for use in texlive?

Tags: fonts, texlive, mac, tex-gyre-math

This is related to the question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320921/30481), though I couldn't figure out the answer from there.

I'm using TeX Live on a macOS system, and compiling with `xelatex`, using the following code to set up the font:

```
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{parskip}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale = 1.0]
```

When I use the above to use the `TeX Gyre Pagella` font I get the following error:

```
Package fontspec Error: The font "TeX Gyre Pagella" cannot be found.
```

From the discussion in the comments of [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320921/30481) I gather that I probably need to add the font to the Font Book. Indeed, the font doesn't seem to be in it.

Am I supposed to download and install these fonts myself? Or should they be already installed with texlive? If the former is the case, what's the recommended place to download and install these fonts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way of installing fonts on macOS is through [homebrew](https://brew.sh).
Open a terminal and execute:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-fonts
```

finally call:

```
brew cask install font-tex-gyre-pagella font-tex-gyre-pagella-math
```

et voilà, the fonts are on your system.

---

Anyway. As a rule of thumb: If you are using `xelatex`, specify the font by filename:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\begin{document}

Hello \(a + b \)

\end{document}
```

If you are using `lualatex`, you can use the font name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}

Hello \(a + b \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
CNHKTM+TeXGyrePagella-Regular        CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
EHBZSS+TeXGyrePagellaMath-Regular    CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
```

---

This behaviour is also documented in the [fontspec manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf):

[image]

Comment: This is useful, thanks. Why the difference between xelatex and lualatex though?

Comment: @glS I added the explanation from the fontspec manual

Comment: You may have to `brew tap homebrew/cask-fonts` to get the insallation to work.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by simply downloading the TeX Gyre Pagella `otf` font files from fontsquirrel.com [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/tex-gyre-pagella) and for the math fonts from `gust.org` [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/download/index_html).

Once downloaded I just double-clicked on the extracted otf files to install them in the Font Book and then compilation worked without problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you select the font by file name rather than font name you won't run into the problem. On the other hand, it's certainly nice to use the font name so you can create a symbolic link of `/Library/TeX/Root/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype` in `~/Library/Fonts`; e.g. `ln -s /Library/TeX/Root/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype ~/Library/Fonts/TeXOTFFonts` (all on one line of course). When you open Font Book you may have to drag and drop that folder onto Font Book to have it register the fonts.